# Hooking registration form prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I've successfully added a hook to display field in customer creation form in prestashop 1.7. But I'm unable to find which hook should use to handle the form submission for validation and processing the form.

```
class MyModule extends Module {
    ...
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() 
        && $this->registerHook('displayCustomerAccountForm') 
    }
    public function hookDisplayCustomerAccountForm($params) {
          return $this->display(__FILE__, 'hookDisplayCustomerAccountForm.tpl');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to validate the form before submission and then use the Hook **actionCustomerAccountAdd** to process the form data.

You can find the hook actionCustomerAccountAdd in /classes/form/CustomerPersister.php